# Removing pixels within given threshold in ArcGIS Pto

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, ndvi, landsat, pixel

I have a time series of Landsat Tiles where I have attempted to mask out the clouds on each image and calculated NDVI but still get some outlier pixels.

Is there a way for me to remove outlier pixels from the images for example by saying that within each set of images, the value can not increase or decrease more than a given value ( i.e 0.1 for NDVI ) between each given landsat scene in ArcGIS Pro?